# Having issues computing the average of compound sentiment values for each text file in a folder

Tags: python-3.x

```
# below is the sentiment analysis code written for sentence-level analysis
import glob
import os
import nltk.data
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk import sentiment
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Next, VADER is initialized so I can use it within the Python script
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

# I will also initialize the 'english.pickle' function and give it a short 
name
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

#Each of the text file is listed from the folder speeches
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'cnn_articles', '*.txt'))

text = []
#iterate over the list getting each file
for file in files:
#open the file and then call .read() to get the text
with open(file) as f:
    text.append(f.read())
text_str = "\n".join(text)
# This breaks up the paragraph into a list of strings. 
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text_str )

sent = 0.0
count = 0

# Iterating through the list of sentences and extracting the compound scores 

for sentence in sentences:
    count +=1
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
    sent += scores['compound'] #Adding up the overall compound sentiment 

# print(sent, file=open('cnn_compound.txt', 'a'))
if count != 0:
sent = float(sent / count)

print(sent, file=open('cnn_compound.txt', 'a'))
```

With these lines of code, I have been able to get the average of all the compound sentiment values for all the text files. What I really want is the 
    average compound sentiment value for each text file, such that if I have 10 
    text files in the folder, I will have 10 floating point values representing 
    each of the text file. So that I can plot these values against each other. 
    Kindly assist me as I am very new to Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
  # below is the sentiment analysis code written for sentence-level analysis
  import os, string, glob, pandas as pd, numpy as np
  import nltk.data
  from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
  from nltk import sentiment
  from nltk import word_tokenize

  # Next, VADER is initialized so I can use it within the Python 
  script
  sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
  exclude = set(string.punctuation)
  # I will also initialize the 'english.pickle' function and give 
  it a short 
  name
  tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

  #Each of the text file is listed from the folder speeches
  files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'cnn_articles', 
  '*.txt'))

 text = []
 sent = 0.0
 count = 0
 cnt = 0
 #iterate over the list getting each file
 for file in files:
     f = open(file).read().split('.')
     cnt +=1
     count = (len(f))
     for sentence in f:
         if sentence not in exclude:
              scores = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
              print(scores)
              break
              sent += scores['compound']
          average = round((sent/count), 4)
          t = [cnt, average]
          text.append(t)
          break

   df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns=['Article Number', 'Average 
   Value'])
    #
    #df.to_csv(r'Result.txt', header=True, index=None, sep='"\t\" 
    +"\t\"', mode='w')
    df.to_csv('cnn_result.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: how to give weight-age to count of reviews for each file. Like in File 1 there is only 1 negative reviews of total  10 Reviews and in File 2 there can be 5 -ve reviews from 100 reviews... and in File 3 there can be 100-ve from 10000 reviews... do we need to add weigh-age for counts for each file?